# What design pattern is implemented by the PreparedStatementSetter from Spring JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

PreparedStatementMapper implementations are used to set the parameters for a java.sql.PreparedStatement.

Javadoc is here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementSetter.html

In this a Command design pattern implementation ? 
If not, then what DP is it ?

Comment: Not everything is a design pattern.

Comment: True, but in this case I think the question is valid. Spring makes heavy use of design patterns, plus the usage strongly points to a Command implementation.

Comment: Why do you think it's a Command?

Comment: When implementing the interface, you separate the object that makes the request  from the way the request is implemented. As I know this is the main requirement of the Command. Also the roles from the pattern can be identified up to a point (invoker, receiver, command).